# Is it posible to use spirng security acl with spring webflux?

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-security-acl

I want to start spring web flux project with spring security acl, But I couldn't find any tutorial. Is it possible to merge this two project together and use in single project?

Answer (score 0):

spring ACL is included in spring security, so you don't need to pull it in separately.

Just because there are no tutorials, doesn't mean you can't use it. There is plenty of information about it in the [official spring security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#domain-acls).